# Wordpress Category List Link to First Post

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

I am loading a category list in wordpress by using this function:

```
<?php wp_list_cats($args = array( 'current_category'   => 0, 'hide_empty'  => 1) );?>
```

Can anyone tell me how I can make the category links link to the category first post?

ie:

At the moment Category A links to url.../category/category-a

I would like Category A to link to its first post instead so url.../category-a/first-post

I tried chaning the taxonomy template which worked witht he following:

```
<?php
/*
Redirect To First Child
*/
if (have_posts()) {
 while (have_posts()) {
   the_post();
   $pagekids = get_pages("child_of=".$post->ID."&sort_column=menu_order");
   $firstchild = $pagekids[0];
   wp_redirect(get_permalink($firstchild->ID));
 }
}
?>
```

I just need a neater solution where i dont need to modify the actual wordpress files.

Thanks

Comment: It seems that `wp_list_cats()` is deprecated, use `wp_list_categories()`

Answer (score 1):

Best that i can come up with, `$posts` array now contains links to first post in each category. Put this code in functions.php:

```
function first_categories( $echo = false ) {
    $categories = get_categories();

    // array to hold links
    $posts = array();
    foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
        $post = get_posts( array( 'posts_per_page' => 1, 'post_type' => 'post', 'category' => $category->cat_ID ) );
        $posts[] = '<a href="'.get_permalink( $post[0]->ID ).'">'.$category->name.'</a>';
    }

    if ( $echo ) echo implode( '', $posts );
    else return $posts;
}
```

In template file to just show the links use:

```
<?php first_categories( true ) ?>
```

Or, if you want to wrap links within HTML use something like:

```
<ul>
<?php foreach( first_categories() as $category ) : ?>
    <li><?php echo $category; ?></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Hope it helps.